# Seven robot ants that stay forever on a rod

Tags: mathematics

You must place 7 robot ants on a long rod and set each of them to move left or right starting at time 0. You can set any positive speed for each ant. When 2 or more ants meet, they turn around. When an ant reaches the end it falls off.

Show that you can place and set the ants in such a way that none of them ever falls off.

---

Bonus question: Can you do this for other odd numbers, too?

Comment: Since someone tried to wiggle out of the intended wording with the last problem, perhaps clarify that "left or right" is along the direction of the rod/parallel to its run/equivalent to moving along a long but not infinite axis

Comment: What happens if I put two ants with the same starting position and direction and speed?

Comment: @justhalf   Starting positions must be different.

Comment: I have found that for 3 ants is impossible. Interesting problem.

Comment: @justhalf how? can you elaborate a bit

Comment: The general idea is to look at ant configuration (position and direction) at the beginning, and after a cycle (to limit the range, there must be a cycle). They must be exactly the same. With 3 ants, after 1 cycle you can calculate that the position will not be exactly the same (in order to be exactly the same, one of the ants' speed need to be 0).

Comment: The case for 7 ants still has no answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Picture showing how to place 4,7 or 10 ants:

> [image]

x-axis is time, y-axis is position. The 4 black ants alone are viable as are the blacks together with the 3 blues or all 10.

Ants here move either at speed 1 or 1/3. Except for the first and last ones, the slower ants can be left out.

Therefore this construction yields solutions for 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ... ants.

P.S.: 5 is also possible:

> [image]

Comment: One of those where a well presented diagram says it all. Great answer!

Comment: Worth noting that this involves instances of three ants meeting. (Yes, this is allowed by the rules.) (Maybe 3+ ants meeting is needed to get 7 or any odd number?)

Comment: Does this mean that 5 ants is not possible?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky No, it only gives positive answers.

Comment: Congratulations! You've solved the most difficult 5 ants case!